# bxSlider - onSlideAfter

Tags: javascript, angular, bxslider

```
paramsSlider = {
        slideWidth: 76,
        slideMargin: 10,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 10,
        pager: false,
        controls: true,
        moveSlides: 5,

        onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
            let count = Math.floor(this.getSlideCount()/5)-1;
        }
    };
```

how can I get the value moveSlides inside the function onSlideAfter?
if I try to apply like a this.moveSlides, I get `undefined`

maybe I don’t understand something, but if I try this way, I get undefined again

```
countSlides: 5; 
paramsSlider = { 
    slideWidth: 76, 
    slideMargin: 10, 
    minSlides: 1, 
    maxSlides: 10, 
    pager: false, 
    controls: true, 
    moveSlides: this.countSlides, 
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) { 
        console.log(this.countSlides) 
    }, 
}
```

Comment: if you want moveSlides value. you can declare variable outside declaration and use it at both places.

Comment: maybe I don’t understand something, but if I try this way, I get undefi again
`countSlides: 5;

    paramsSlider = {
        slideWidth: 76,
        slideMargin: 10,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 10,
        pager: false,
        controls: true,
        moveSlides: this.countSlides,

        onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
            console.log(this.countSlides)
        }, 
}`

Comment: Update new codes in the question. It is practically unreadable in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for it.

```js
const paramsSlider = {
  slideWidth: 76,
  slideMargin: 10,
  minSlides: 1,
  maxSlides: 10,
  pager: false,
  controls: true,
  moveSlides: 5,
  get moveSlidesVal() {
    return this.moveSlides;
  },
  onSlideAfter: function() {
    let count = Math.floor(this.getSlideCount() / 5) - 1;
    count += this.moveSlidesVal;
    return count;
  },
  getSlideCount: function() {
    return 100; // sample value
  }
};

document.write(paramsSlider.onSlideAfter()); // 24 expected
```

Comment: unfortunately, I stiil get undefined

Comment: I edited the answer to include a snippet which works as expected.